Sharepoint Online Audit Log API - Missing Operations
I am extracting data using SharePoint Online Audit Log subscription, using API endpoint like below:
https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/*******/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.SharePoint&startTime=2024-07-17T00:00:00&endTime=2024-07-17T23:59:59
Everything seems to work and below is a list of some of the distinct Operations we get in the result:
AccessRequestApproved
AccessRequestCreated
AddedToGroup
ClientViewSignaled
CommentCreated
CommentsDisabled
CompanyLinkCreated
CompanyLinkUsed
FileAccessed
FileAccessedExtended
FileCheckedIn
FileCheckedOut
FileCheckOutDiscarded
FileCopied
FileDownloaded
FileModified
FileModifiedExtended
FileMoved
FilePreviewed
FileRecycled
FileRenamed
FileSyncDownloadedFull
FileSyncUploadedFull
FileUploaded
FileVersionRecycled
FileVersionsAllDeleted
FolderCreated
FolderDeleted
FolderModified
FolderMoved
FolderRecycled
FolderRenamed
GroupAdded
GroupRemoved
GroupUpdated
ListColumnCreated
ListColumnDeleted
ListColumnUpdated
ListContentTypeUpdated
ListCreated
ListDeleted
ListItemCreated
ListItemRecycled
ListItemUpdated
ListItemViewed
ListUpdated
ListViewCreated
ListViewed
ListViewUpdated
PagePrefetched
PageViewed
PageViewedExtended
RemovedFromGroup
SearchQueryPerformed
SharingInheritanceBroken
SharingInheritanceReset
SharingInvitationBlocked
SharingRevoked
SharingSet
SiteCollectionAdminAdded
SiteCollectionAdminRemoved
SiteContentTypeUpdated
WACTokenShared
What we are noticing is that we used to get an Operation called SearchQueryPerformed, but since May 1st we are not getting any data for that Operation, anyone knows anything about it.
Tired searching in Sharepoint sites then importing API data, nothing showed up for SearchQueryPerformed operation

would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?
